# Missing column header when converting to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridviewcolumn

After converting the datagridview data to excel i have a missing column header. Tried a few codes in different guide but still do not get the header am i missing any thing?

```
private void convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "Unmatched";
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].Visible)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.FileName = "report";
        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        } 
        app.Quit();
    }
```

[what excel have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC1VP.png)

[What it should have and what is in datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siN18.png)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;`. Run to the breakpoint. Hover over `HeaderText`. What is shown?

Comment: It just shows 1 column header (Close date) but dont show the other column header.

Comment: There are 2 column header in my database 1.Close Date 2. workorder . But my current code when i load it to dataGridView it has 2 column but converting to excel only has 1 ( close date).

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through your first `for` loop and checking the `HeaderText` values.

Comment: Headertext values shows close date only missing the workorder

Comment: I added image on what the ouput to excel have and what datagridview have

Comment: Thanks i got it alr.

Answer (score 0):

```
worksheet.Cells[i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
```